# Topological Classification of Band Insulators (in terms of Green's functions)

Tags: topology, greens-functions, topological-insulators

I am currently reading [Topological Classification and Stability of Fermi Surfaces](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.240404) by Y. X. Zhao and Z. D. Wang (PRL **110**, 240404 (2013)).

They remark that the Green's function (along the complex frequency axis) can be viewed as a mapping $S^p \to \mathrm{GL}(N,\mathbb{C})$, where $p$ is the co-dimension of the Fermi surface. It is then natural to classify the Fermi surface by the topological character of this mapping which falls into some instance of $\pi_p(\mathrm{GL}(N,\mathbb{C})$). In particular, one can define the winding number

$$
N_p = C_p \int_{S^p} \mathrm{tr}~(G\textbf{d} G^{-1})^p,
$$

where $C_p = -~p!~/~( (2p+1)! (2\pi i )^{p+1})$ .

I am now wondering how these ideas are related to the topology of *band insulators*:

1. Since the Brillouin zone is periodic, an insulating band represents a compact manifold of some co-dimension $p$  (similar to a Fermi surface). And hence I should be able to write down the winding number $N_p$ in terms of Green's functions. Is this a straightforward generalisation of the formula presented above?
2. I suppose that in this case the Green's function needs to be viewed along the *real frequency axis* in order to pick up the correct singularities. Is this correct?